# Using AutoLayout in Custom Views vs View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, autolayout

I've been using the old way of doing things for quite a while, by setting the origin and size on individual frames and putting things exactly how I want them on the screen. Now i'm trying to move to using AutoLayout. But I'm having a bit of trouble that I cant seem to find an exact answer for.

I'm used to mainly using code for creating views and view controllers. As such, I've come familiar with creating custom view classes which combine multiple views to my liking. For example, i have a custom Profile Pin view that combines a UIImageView and a UILabel into one view to represent a profileImage and username. I then use these custom views in different places as a part of other views and view controllers.

It seems to me that autolayout is intended for views that need re-adjust sizing when screen orientation changes, or for readjusting subviews for different screen sizes.

My question is, should I be meticulous and use autolayout for custom views that have static placement and sizes? Like the UIImageVIew and the UILabel view in the Profile Pin view I described? The positions for the UIImageView and the UILabel view wont change, but the position for the Profile Pin view (their parent) probably will. Should I be using Autolayout for everything? Or is this not a situation that AutoLayout was intended for?

Comment: Autolayout is very useful any time that you want your layout to be dependent on the superview that your views are inside. For example if you always want your views to be positioned a certain distance from the edges of the superview, or if you want your views to have bounds relative to that of the superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom view has static contents where the size and position of it's subviews never change, then feel free to stick with manual frames internally. There's not much benefit to Autolayout in that case.

What you *should* do, though, is override `intrinsicContentSize` and return the correct size. This allows any parent view to use Autolayout to position and know the size of your custom view.

Many UIKit components use this technique - `UISwitch` being a prime example.

Comment: Ahh. Thats kind of what I was hoping to hear. Thank you!